# Problem with IIS locking my uploaded file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a small upload application where i upload a file using a webservice (asmx), check the MD5 and verify it. Problem is that when i verify the file it says that the file is locked by another process. Below is my code for uploading and verifying:

```
private static object padlock = new object();
```

Chunking the upload file in smaller bites and uploading each of them

```
[WebMethod]
        public void LargeUpload(byte[] content, string uniqueName)
        {
            lock (padlock)
            {
                string path = Server.MapPath(PartialDir + "/" + uniqueName);
                BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write));
                writer.Write(content);
                writer.Flush();
                writer.Close();
                writer = null;
            }
        }
```

After the last one insert it into my database. After this the client verifies the file by requesting the MD5:

```
[WebMethod]
        public int EndLargeUpload(string name, int folderId, long length, string uniqueName, int customerid)
        {
            lock (padlock)
            {
                string path = Server.MapPath(PartialDir + "/" + uniqueName);
                string newPath = Server.MapPath(RepositoryDir + "/" + uniqueName);
                File.Copy(path, newPath);
                //delete partial
                File.Delete(path);
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(uniqueName);
                string newFileName = uniqueName;
                GWFile newFile = new GWFile();
                newFile.DiscName = newFileName;
                newFile.FileName = name;
                newFile.FolderId = folderId;
                newFile.Description = "";
                newFile.Size = (int)length;
                newFile.DiscFolder = Server.MapPath("/Repository");
                newFile.DiscRelativePath = "/Repository/" + newFile.DiscName;
                newFile.CustomerId = customerid;
                IGWFileRepository fileRepository = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IGWFileRepository>();


                fileRepository.SaveFile(newFile);
                return newFile.Id;
            }
        }
```

After the EndLargeUpload() method the client calls the RequestMD5 method with the id of the file, this call excepts with an exception that it cannot open the file ".....xxx..." because it s being used by another process...

```
private string GetMD5HashFromFile(string fileName)
            {
                lock (padlock)
                {
                    using (FileStream file = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open)) // <-- excepts here
                    {
                        MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
                        byte[] retVal = md5.ComputeHash(file);
                        file.Close();

                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        for (int i = 0; i < retVal.Length; i++)
                        {
                            sb.Append(retVal[i].ToString("x2"));
                        }
                        return sb.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
```

I used the process explorer from sysinternals to view the file, it says that the file is locked by the web server ( pls refer to this img: http://screencast.com/t/oqvqWXLjku) - how can the web server lock it? can I work around this?

Comment: Hint: You don't need to close a BinaryWriter in triplicate (flush, close, set to null), calling `Close()` is quite enough. Or even better, you could use a `using` block.

Comment: Do you have any other file I/O in this application that would touch these files?

Comment: For this kind of project I recommend using `IIS` instead of `Cassini`

Comment: Does the SaveFile method of the filerepository touch the file in any way? Also, I noticed that you are calling both Close and Dispose on the filestream in the MD5 method. In which line are you getting an error?

Comment: I have no other file I/O at all. The SaveFile method in my repository is ONLY database and it does not touch the file. I have a feeling that the File.Copy method still holds a ref to the file. Please note that the file is copied from old locatio and the screenshot shows it being locked in the new position.

@Jakob: I get an error in the "using" line in the MD5 method

Comment: Solved!! From my client i accessed the webservice before requesting the MD5, i had a method to verify if the file existed on disk. That method apparantly did a screenshot of the image uploaded (cant remember making that one) - but most important - NOW IT WORKS :-)

Cheers all, for helping out

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Switched to IIS,  and the problem seems to go away...

Comment: I have same problem, please explain what do you mean with "Switched to IIS"?

Answer (score 0):

How about the last two lines in the EndLargeUpload method:

```
IGWFileRepository fileRepository = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IGWFileRepository>();
fileRepository.SaveFile(newFile);
```

Is it possible that IGWFileRepository.SaveFile() is not closing the file properly?